# Do we ever find out what Ivy wished for?

Tags: urban-fantasy, the-hollows, kim-harrison

In [Dead Witch Walking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061567191) by Kim Harrison, early in the book, Ivy is given a wish.  Later in the book Rachel - the POV character - notices that Ivy's necklace (which contained the charm she could use to get a wish) is gone.  The implication is that she has used her wish.

I've recently finished reading book two of the series, [The Good, the Bad, and the Undead](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061567310), and despite quite a bit of 'screen time' for Ivy and quite of bit of revelations on her part (and about her) there's no mention of her wish.

Is this a dropped plot thread?  Or it this something that is explained in a later book?

If it is explained in a later book, which one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns up in book 7, [White Which, Black Curse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061138029).

> For reasons I don't fully recall, Ivy gifts it to Mia, a banshee. The banshee uses it to allow her to be with her human mate without killing him.

Comment: Book 7?  Wow...that shows an impressive amount of planning...or an author who left dangling plot threads on purpose, to pick up later.

Comment: Yeah. I don't recall any foreshadowing through the books that would indicate it was planned, so my guess is the author just left it hanging until she found a convenient way to use it. Who knows though - could have been planned from the start.

Comment: Much as I liked all of her books, I don't really see many signs of long-term plotting. Especially when compared to other series', such as the Dresden Files.

Comment: Specifically, Ivy explains what happened to her wish in chapter thirteen of _White Witch, Black Curse_.